# Can a semicolon be used to separate phrases?

Tags: punctuation

It is no small consolation to remember that even the mightiest of powers flounder on the desolate shoals of terrorism; [semicolon](https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/columns/pulwama-attack-india-pakistanwhos-winning-losing-5597285)just look at the Americans in Afghanistan[Link 1](https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/columns/pulwama-attack-india-pakistanwhos-winning-losing-5597285)

Primary education will require serious engagement with the states; [semicolon]higher education with a large number of other existing regulatory bodies and institutions.[Link 2](https://indianexpress.com/article/opinion/columns/delivery-is-in-the-detail)

Comment: We like to see evidence of effort before questions. If you google **use of semi colon**, you will find scores of sites that illustrate its usage. Have you tried to see if any of them answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

1

> It is no small consolation to remember that even the mightiest of powers flounder on the desolate shoals of terrorism; [you can] just look at the Americans in Afghanistan.

Example 1 consists of two independent **clauses**, not phrases, and the use of semicolon to separate them is fine.  The bracketed subject and modal verb are understood and have been omitted.

2

> Primary education will require serious engagement with the states; higher education [will require serious engagement] with a large number of other existing regulatory bodies and institutions.

Example 2 consists of two independent **clauses**, not phrases, and the use of semicolon to separate them is fine.  There is parallelism here, and the bracketed verb and direct object have been omitted.

Comment: +1, though I think the first example is an idiomatic use of the imperative mood (command form) rather than an instance of an understood "you can".